# wso2 automatic failover in esb cluster (on worker nodes)

Tags: wso2, esb, failovercluster, automatic-failover

now wso2 ELB is deprecated so we have to use nginx plus.
How ensure an automatic failover with worker nodes attached to an ESB cluster?
have we to implement a check health on nginx plus or is there a wso2 configuration on esb cluster ?
Thank you
Hassan boutougha

Comment: Normally you should be able to configure it in LB. There is no need of having any additional configurations.
See http://serverfault.com/questions/140990/nginx-automatic-failover-load-balancing

Comment: Thank you harsha, so why use ESB cluster ? Because, we can synchronize every esb artifacts on governance registry (sequences and endpoints). So ESB cluster plumbing with svn repo is only needed to synchronize API and proxy services? cheers